# jquery validation word count integration

Tags: jquery, validation, count, cpu-word

How can I integrate word count into bassistance.de validation? For example, i dont want people to enter more than 50 words, and it should show an error to indicate it.

```
<form action="done.php" method="post" id="mainform"  class="validate">
<textarea name="message" rows="4" id="message"  class="required" ></textarea>   
</form>
```

Here is all I have, but i dont know where to go from here

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("form.validate").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
               form.submit();
    }
})
```

});

any assistance here would be appreciated, i'm not familiar with this plugin at all.

Comment: In American English, at least before the rise of the word processor, a "word" was considered 5 characters, which was based on monospaced fonts and 1 inch margins, such that you got 25 "words" per line, and 10 lines per page (double-spaced), etc etc. Bottom line, I'd recommend going with a character count validation as a "word" is much harder to define (ask a linguist). In my example, it would be a 250 character minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a minimum charachter count, based on what you think is the average word length (I still stand behind 5). So that would be:

```
$("#mainform").validate({
  rules: {
    message: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 250
    }
  }
});
```

#### Update:

If ajax is an option, you could use the `remote` rule.  I think it would along the lines of:

```
$("#test").validate({
    rules: {
        message: {
            remote: {
                url: "check_wordcount.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    wordcount: 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having some issues with it, with the timing, but I think some of that is just me rushing things, but it does work.  In this case, the remote script must return `true` for the element name, so my php script looks like:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$wordcount = (int) $_POST['wordcount'];
$valid = (str_word_count($message) >= $wordcount);

echo json_encode(array('message' => $valid));
```

Comment: i really need word count, but this might be good enough. thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that adds a custom rule to the validator a simple, reusable, clean way to get the job done.

```
$.validator.addMethod("wordCount", function(value, element, wordCount) {

    return value.split(' ').length <= wordCount;

}, 'Exceeded word count');'Exceeded word count of ' + len + ' or less');
```

How to use it

```
rules: {
  fieldName: { 
    required: true,
    wordCount: 300
  }
},
messages: {
  fieldName: { 
    required: 'Statement of justification is required',
    wordCount:'Please shorten to 300 words or less.'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go through http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/10/jquery-plugin-word-counter-textarea.html

or if you jus want to count a word length use

```
   var myLength = $("#myTextbox").val().length;
```

$("#mytextbox") finds the textbox by its id.

.val() gets the value of the input element entered by the user, which is a string.

.length gets the number of characters in the string.
 and in any event you can check it and give alert msg.