# wordCount not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an issue in validating textarea with word count 500.If the number of paragraphs increased the count increase by one.In this case total word count not accepting 500.

**Sample Code**

```
$('#wizard2').validate(
{
  rules: {

 project_desc: {
         required: true,
         wordCount: ['500'],
    },
 },
)};
```

Comment: Please some more code

Comment: one textarea only.

Comment: robins  you need to provide an example link like fiddle of your problem. You yourself understood that the code given by you is too less to check/rectify  your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery validation word count integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084673/jquery-validation-word-count-integration)

Comment: updated the question please check

Comment: You used wordCount method but jquery validator does not come with such method. You need to make your own custom rule first and then you can define rule. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19233936/5518973)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validator Minimum Required Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233901/jquery-validator-minimum-required-words)